# Dynamic image path not working in drupal 7

Tags: php, html, image, drupal, drupal-7

I tried giving the image path like

```
 <img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/images/yourimage.gif" />
```

in Drupal 7.
But it's not working. The images are still not loading.
 If I give the path like 
 its working.

I heard its not a good practice.

Is there any other way to add image source in drupal?

Comment: You are going to need to provide a more complete code sample. Eg, where does `$directory` come from?

Comment: Could you show us the PHP code please? I do understand you're just doing the basic php way of placing the src but still would be useful.

Comment: Check at page source and see how image paths are created and what's wrong/missing.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. Where did you put your image? Did you use custom content type to save your image? Did you used IMCE in a text field? Do you mean this image is in your template folder, and you call it in your html or page template?
Usually, an image is saved in a node content, customized by editing/creating a content type suitable to the data you want to show.